# How can i print space separated string? I get the output without space

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, char, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   char str[101];
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      scanf("%s ",&str[i]);
   }
   printf("%s ",str);
}
```

I am getting the output without space For exammple if input is (a p p l e) i am getting (apple) but i need to get (a p p l e)

Comment: What is the value , you are providing to n ?

Comment: You are reading multiple strings into one variable, offset from each other and overlapping.

Comment: `scanf(%s)` stops at the first whitespace. You cannot scan strings with spaces that way.

Comment: You probably need to look into `fgets`. very important: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input, otherwise you'll get some surprises.

Answer (score 1):

The format `"%s"` is used to read a sequence of characters until a white space is encountered,

Instead of the conversion specifier `%s` use the conversion specifier `%c` if you are going to use a loop.

For example

```
int i = 0;

while ( i < n && scanf( "%c", str + i ) == 1 && str[i] != '\n' ) ++i;
str[i] = '\0';
```

Instead of the loop you could use the standard function `fgets` as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//...

fgets( str, n + 1, stdin );
str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

puts( str );
```

Pay attention to that the expression `n + 1` shall be not greater than `101` due to this declaration

```
char str[101];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last `printf` you are just calling the String, you're not putting spaces.

You need another `for` to call the String letter by letter, and put spaces between them.

Like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   char str[101];
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      scanf("%s ",&str[i]);
   }
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
           printf("%c ",str[i]);
      }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s ",&str[i]);` is still wrong. either scan for a single character or use separate strings

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `scanf` to `scanf(" %[^\n]",&str[i]);` you should get your desired result. `%s` looks for whitespace-separated strings, while `%[^\n]` will takes the entire string up to a newline.